# Secure Authentication Protocol

Tags: security, authentication, azure, web, cloud-hosting

I'm looking for a simple authentication protocol (OpenID, Active Directory, ??) for users to log into my website. It's hosted on Windows Azure. High levels of security are required. What can you recommend and why that particular choice?

Note: At this point in time I will not be using SSL so no plain-text passwords can be transmitted. I will however be transitioning to an SSL environment in the future.

Comment: No SSL == No "High levels of security". Most of the authentication protocols out there rely on SSL. If you won't use SSL then the best bet would be to implement Public Key Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data that your site/service is going to be transmitting across the wire private, sensitive, proprietary, etc? If so, it is ESSENTIAL that you implement SSL in order to prevent anyone with a packet sniffer from being able to syphon data straight from the wire.

In order to perform secure authentication you will need to employ something like SSL to establish a secure communications transport over which you can request and receive a SAML (or similar) identity token from an identity provider.

If you don't use SSL to protect your communications, it's trivial for a malicious 3rd party to steal the identity token and masquerade as the authenticated user and/or to log/monitor/modify every request for any user of your system!

What are your reasons for not using SSL?